# 404 Error Problems with sCategory Permalink plugin

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

Seems throughout the day my blog seems to show 404 page errors with no pattern. I have to manually change the permalinks from /blog/%scategory%/%postname%/ to default, then back to /blog/%scategory%/%postname%/ in order to fix the permalink issue.

This has been a problem for us for the past six months, and our site gets 10k views a day. While that is not a lot, it does give us a huge problem when at certain periods of the day we have a huge issue where none of our Posts work, yet Pages continue to work fine.

I have extensive conversation on this issue at this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506130/wordpress-permalinks-not-staying) where I have narrowed a few things down, and at this point I believe the sCategory Permalink is the issue. I need help understanding what is causing this issue, and more importantly fixing this so it never happens again.

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped using that plugin a long time ago. I don't think you really need it anymore honestly. I just remember it did the same thing that I was able to do when I disabled it, so I stopped using it. I don't think its still supported by the developer either, so may be out of date.

I may be wrong, but then again I use the least amount of plugins as I can and build most things into my themes.

Comment: i hate using plugins as well. can you advise how i can use the same perm setup w/o the plugin? i'm confused how to do that while keeping the urls we have set up w/sCategory plugin. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your Wordpress URL and your Site URL in General Settings set up right? 
You can set the /blog/ directory there so that WordPress uses a different directory, Once you set it to http://sitename.com/blog/ you can just use /%scategory%/%postname%/ in permalinks.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

If that doesn't help, perhaps this might be able to. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/how-to-create-your-permalink-structure-more-user-and-seo-friendly/